# Some difficulties in implementing markdown editor

Tags: plugin-development

How to use the metadata window and release control window that have been implemented in the classic editor in the custom editor page.

I want to say that the interaction of the metabox element of the wordpress editor is particularly troublesome. I am writing a brand new markdown editor of WP-ReliableMD. I used replace_editor to rewrite the interface, but I want to use the metabox element of the WP editor itself. I don't know how to obtain and process these interactive information normally and effectively at the js layer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, is metadata window referring to metaboxes? What is the release control window? Which editor are you referring to? The classic editor or the block editor?

Comment: Doesn't the editing page of the classic editor have various windows besides the editing area? It contains the metadata input window, the window extended by the custom field group plug-in, and the window for controlling article publishing, tagging and classification. I hope to migrate to the edit page of my plug-in

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by windows, no APIs refer to windows and neither does any of the UI text, but I suspect you meant metaboxes, calling them windows implies browser windows or popups/modal dialogs. Given that you've used the `replace_editor` filter, what are you having difficulty with? Remember that questions here need to be stated clearly and in a way that you can mark an answer as factually correct. Are you asking how to display the metaboxes from the classic editor? You mentioned javascript though 

Comment: Yes, I hope to port the js interaction of the metadata box of the classic editor and the selection box of article publishing control, label and category catalog to the implementation of my custom editor, but I don’t know how to do it

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem?